# how to apply `weight` for imbalanced validation data when to evaluate model performance?

Tags: classification, predictive-models, boosting, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes

I am doing a classification model on imbalanced dataset (fraud). The way to preprocess imbalanced dataset follows [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164693/adding-weights-to-logistic-regression-for-imbalanced-data) - basically I don't do down sample/over sample, but apply `weight` to 1 for all fraud observations(rare), and 10 for all good observations.

After apply `weight` to the full data, I split the full dataset to training dataset and validation dataset, obviously the validation is also imbalanced with `weight`.

My question is :

1. Should I use the `weight` column for validation data when computed metrics(for Gains/Lift, AUC, confusion matrices, logloss, etc.) (ideally consistently between training and testing) ?  I am trying to use `skleanr.metrics.classification_report` to evaluate the performance and noticed there is `sample_weight` parameter. However, checking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093185/how-to-understand-sample-weight-in-sklearn-metrics) where it answers that:

> The sample-weight parameter is only used during training.

2. I am trying to evaluate if there is data drift and if the model needs to be retrained . For the incoming new test dataset, which is directly sampled from the last month data (let's call it `new_data` ), I do not have a `weight` column for this `new_data`. It is possible that the distribution of the minority class changes significantly over time. In this regard, how to measure data drift ?

Thanks!